# How to use eCharts to display a daily stock chart combined with a quarterly revenue data chart

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have two datasets which I want to display on an eCharts canvas, as two separate line charts:

1. a quarterly revenue chart, and
2. a daily stock price chart.

Using the code below, both line charts are displayed, but because the datasets have different array lengths, the revenues line chart is being squeezed into the left hand side of the canvas, while the stock price chart is displayed properly in full width. Also, the x-axes aren't aligned with each other, because the date-ranges don't overlap completely (the quarterly data starts earlier than the price data, see below example).

The first, long dataset, containing *daily* stock prices, looks as follows:

```
    var dailyStockprices = [123,124,125, ... etc] // array length 600
    var dailyDates = ["2019-01-02","2019-01-03","2019-01-04", ... etc] // array length 600
```

The second, very short dataset, containing *quarterly* revenues, looks as follows:

```
    var quarterlyRevenues = [123,124,125, ... etc]  // array length 20
    var quarterlyDates = ["2018-09-30","2018-12-31","2019-03-31", ... etc] // array length 20
```

The eCharts code looks as follows:

```
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('mainchart1'));

    option = {
      xAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
        data: dailyDates
      }, {
        type: 'category',
        data: quarterlyDates
      }],
      yAxis: [{
        type: 'value'
      }, {
        type: 'value'
      }],
      series: [{
        data: dailyStockprices,
        type: 'line',
        yAxisIndex: 0
      }, {
        data: quarterlyRevenues,
        type: 'line',
        yAxisIndex: 1
      }]
    };
    myChart.setOption(option);
```

Here's a *simplified* JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/frankmarks/szm1f20j/9/

How can I make both line charts display properly, i.e. full width, on the same canvas, with both x-Axes being aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution, which is to set the axis type to 'time' instead of 'category', which automatically align the axis alignment and answers my question entirely.

Further explanation as to how to format the data is given in the eCharts documentation here: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series.data

**Excerpt:**

When a dimension corresponds to a time axis (type is 'time'), the value can be:

- a timestamp, like 1484141700832, which represents a UTC time.
- a date string, in one of the formats below: a subset of ISO 8601, only
  including (all of these are treated as local time unless timezone is
  specified, which is consistent with moment): only part of
  year/month/date/time are specified: '2012-03', '2012-03-01',
  '2012-03-01 05', '2012-03-01 05:06'. separated by "T" or a space:
  '2012-03-01T12:22:33.123', '2012-03-01 12:22:33.123'.
- timezone specified: '2012-03-01T12:22:33Z', '2012-03-01T12:22:33+8000',
  '2012-03-01T12:22:33-05:00'.
- other date string format (all of these
  are treated as local time): '2012', '2012-3-1', '2012/3/1',
  '2012/03/01', '2009/6/12 2:00', '2009/6/12 2:05:08', '2009/6/12
  2:05:08.123'.
- a JavaScript Date instance created by user: Caution,
  when using a data string to create a Date instance, browser differences and inconsistencies should be considered.

For example: In chrome, new Date('2012-01-01') is treated as a Jan 1st 2012 in UTC, while new Date('2012-1-1') and new Date('2012/01/01') are treated as Jan 1st 2012 in local timezone. In safari new Date('2012-1-1') is not supported.

So if you intent to perform new Date(dateString), it is strongly recommended to use a time parse library (e.g., moment), or use echarts.number.parseDate.